# How to use an Object in a trait by using its type in Scala

Tags: scala, object, generics, traits, scala-3

I was trying to implement some Model - Row implementation similar that Rails (Activerecord)  in Scala. I simply trying to do this;

```
trait Model[A]:
  def query = "model has this good stuff I want to use in RowData"

trait RowData[B <: Model[B]]:
  def query = B.query

case class Person(name: String, age: Int) extends RowData[Person]

object Person extends Model[Person]

Person("onur", 38).query // I wan't to use like this
```

I'm getting Not found: B on `RowData` trait. Because `Model[A]` is an object I supposed that I can use it as is.

You can try in here: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/U3MOJhFXSS2O8fanY5aIpg

Comment: `Model[A]` is not an object, it is a type. But you have bigger problems because `Person` can't extend `RowData` because it isn't a subtype of `Model` as required by the type parameter on `RowData`.

Comment: It doesn't have to be this way. I'm just trying to use an object's trait method in another trait. Could it be possible?

Comment: Onur did my question solve your problem? If so, please accept the answer :)

Comment: There is no real way to force a connection between a class and an object. You probably want a typeclass instead of subtyping polymorphism: https://gist.github.com/BalmungSan/c19557030181c0dc36533f3de7d7abf4

Comment: Do you think, that object Person extends Model so in RowData, B is Person so you think B.query should work? Is this somewhat what you expected? https://scastie.scala-lang.org/hkBMyYJSSUuwhJkzDi5GFg

Comment: Yes, this was what I exactly wanted. Can you turn your comment into an answer so I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the requirement is to use the companion object's method, but the issue with this solution is that, given this code:

```
trait RowData[B <: Model[B]]:
  def query = B.query
```

Because `B` is supposed to be the companion object, it cannot be passed as a type in `[]`. You need to pass it as an object in parentheses `()`, like [this](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/hkBMyYJSSUuwhJkzDi5GFg):

```
trait Model[A]:
  def query = "model has this good stuff I want to use in RowData"

trait RowData(B: Model[_]):
  def query = B.query

case class Person(name: String, age: Int) extends RowData(Person)

object Person extends Model[Person]

Person("onur", 38).query
```

However, this is not an ideal solution either, because `B` is not enforced to be the companion object you pass for the `RowData` trait. In Scala, we commonly use [Context Bound](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/ca-context-bounds.html) to enforce this, like [this](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/PhawfGhVQNyfrNbZIFS5mA):

```
trait Model[A]:
  def query = "model has this good stuff I want to use in RowData"

trait RowData[B : Model]:
  def query = summon[Model[B]].query

case class Person(name: String, age: Int) extends RowData[Person]

given Person: Model[Person] with {} // Implement custom query method here

Person("onur", 38).query
```

Answer (score 1):

```
trait RowData[B <: Model[B]]:
  def query = B.query
```

This is not supported because (among other reasons) the `query` method might not exist.

The problem is that the type of the companion object is not related to the type of the class. So the fact that `B` is a subclass of `Model[B]` says nothing about the type of the companion object of `B`. And specifically, it does not require the companion object of `B` to be a subclass of `Model[B]` and therefore it is not required to have the appropriate `query` method.

The other problem is that this does not compile:

```
trait RowData[B <: Model[B]]:
  def query = B.query

case class Person(name: String, age: Int) extends RowData[Person]
```

The `RowData` trait requires that `Person` is a subclass of `Model[Person]` but `Person` does not inherit from `Model[Person]`

You either need to have `Person` inherit from `Model` and provide the appropriate `query` method, or look at using a type class for this problem.

Comment: query method should exist because `trait Model[A]` forces it. As I said before, It doesn't have to be this way. I know in my heart that Scala 3 can use an object's method which is forced by a trait in another trait. There might be a solution with Givens or TypeClasses, but I'm not an expert Scala developer to find out.

Comment: As I said, `RowData` doesn't know that the companion object of `B` extends `Model` so it can't call any `Model` methods such as `query`.